# Writing unit tests when the repository holds your most important code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ninject, repository-pattern, entity-attribute-value

I have an EAV system that stores entities in a SQL database, fetches them out and stores them in the cache.  The application is written using the repository pattern because at some point in the future we will probably switch to using a NOSQL database for serving some or all of the data.  I use Ninject to fetch the correct repository at runtime.

A large part of the system's functionality is around storing, retrieving and querying data in an efficient and timely manner.  There is not a huge amount of functionality that doesn't fall into the realm of data access or user interface.

I've read up on unit testing - I understand the theory but haven't put it into practice yet for a few reasons:

- An entity consists of fieldsets, fields, values, each of which has many properties.  Creating any large number of these in code in order to test would require a lot of effort.
- Some of the most crucial parts of my code are in the repositories.  For instance all of the data access goes through a single highly optimised method that fetches entities from the database or cache.
- Using a test database feels like I'm breaking one of the key tenets of unit testing - no external dependencies.

In addition to this the way the repositories are built feels like it's tied into how the data is stored in SQL.  Entities go in one table, fields in another, values in another etc.  So I have a repository for each.  It is my understanding though that in a document store database that the Entity, its field and values would all exist as a single object, removing the need for multiple repositories.  I've considered making my data access more granular in order to move sections of code outside of the repository, but this would compound the problem by forcing me to write the repository interfaces in a way that is designed for retrieving data from SQL.

**Question**: Based on the above, should I accept that I cannot write unit tests for large parts of my code and just test the things I can?

Answer (score 3):

> should I accept that I cannot write unit tests for large parts of my code?

No, you shouldn't accept that. In fact, this is never the case - with enough effort, you can unit test pretty much anything.

Your problem boils down to this: your code relies upon a database, but you cannot use it, because it is an external dependency. You can address this problem by using [*mock objects*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx) - special objects constructed inside your unit test code that present themselves as implementations of database interfaces, and feed your program the data that is required to complete a particular unit test. When your program sends requests to these objects, your unit test code can verify that the requests are correct. When your program expects a particular response, your unit tests give it the response as required by your unit test scenario.

Mocking may be non-trivial, especially in situations when requests and responses are complex. Several libraries exist to help you out with this in .NET, making the task of coding your mock objects almost independent of the structure of the real object. However, the real complexity is often in the behavior of the system that you are mocking - in your case, that's the database. The effort of coding up this complexity is entirely on you, and it does consume a very considerable portion of your coding time.

Answer (score 2):

It appears,  when you say a "unit test", you really mean an "integration test". Because in a unit-test-world there is no database. If you expect to get or insert some data into the external resource, you just  fake it (using mocks, stubs, fakes, spies etc)

> should I accept that I cannot write unit tests for large parts of my
>   code and just test the things I can?

Hard to tell without seeing your code, but it sounds like you can easily unit test it. This is based on your use of the interfaces and the repository pattern. As long as a unit test is independent from other tests, tests only a single piece of functionality, small, simple, does not depend on any external resources - you are good to go.

Do not confuse this with integration and other types of testing. Those may involve real data and may be a bit trickier to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the *proper* Repository pattern testing is easy, because

1. Business layer knows ONLY about the repository interface which deals ONLY with objects known by the layer and doesn't expose ANYTHING related to the actual Db (like EF). Here's where you're using fakes implementing the repository interface.
2. Testing the db access means you're testing the Repo implementation, you get test objects in and out. It's natural for the Repository to be coupled with the db.

Test for repo should be something like this

```
public void add_get_object()
 {
     var entity=CreateSomeTestEntity();
     _repo.Save(entity);
     var loaded=_repo.Get(entity.Id);
     //assert those 2 entities are identical, but NOT using reference
     // either make it implement IEquatable<Entity> or test each property manually
  }
```

These repo tests can be reused with ANY repository implementation: in memory, EF, raven db etc, because it shouldn't matter the implementation, it matters that the repo does what it's required to do (saving/loading business objects).